# How to add a value number when press the button?

Tags: javascript, html

How to add number value when i click button?
For example
If i click 100,000 twice,
200,000 will be entered in the input.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myform button').on('click', function() {
    $('#cvalue').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box">
  <form id="myform">
    <div class="inputdiv">
      <input type="text" id="cvalue" class="money">
    </div>
    <button class="button1" type="button" value="100,000">100,000</button>
    <button class="button1" type="button" value="200,000">200,000</button>
    <button class="button1" type="button" value="300,000">300,000</button>
    <button class="button1" type="button" value="500,000">500,000</button>
    <button class="button1" type="button" value="1,000,000">1,000,000</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: You need to add an unique ID to each button and make a function for each button adding the value to a variable that it has to contain the sum.

Comment: @KevinDoUrden No he doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not trivial

```js
const fmt = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 0 });

$(document).ready(function() {
  const $cvalue = $('#cvalue');
  $('#myform .button1').on('click', function() {
    const val = +$(this).val().replace(/\D/g, "") + +$cvalue.val().replace(/\D/g, "")
    $cvalue.val(fmt.format(val));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box">
  <form id="myform">
    <div class="inputdiv">
      <input type="text" id="cvalue" class="money" value="0">
    </div>
    <button class="button1" type="button" value="100,000">100,000</button>
    <button class="button1" type="button" value="200,000">200,000</button>
    <button class="button1" type="button" value="300,000">300,000</button>
    <button class="button1" type="button" value="500,000">500,000</button>
    <button class="button1" type="button" value="1,000,000">1,000,000</button>
  </form>
```